# Change GitHub username@host prefix for ssh clone click-to-copy

Tags: github

I have two GitHub ssh profiles set up; the default is for my personal account and there is another for my work account. My `~/.ssh/config` looks like this:

```
Host github.com
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal.id_ed25519

Host work
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work.id_ed25519
```

When I clone a work repo, I go to the web UI, click the button to copy, and get `git@github.com:work/repo`, *even when I'm logged in with my work credentials*.

[image: ssh clone repo GitHub interface]

Rather than needing to always remember to change `git@github.com:` to `work:` manually (or forgetting until I try to push and it's rejected), is there a way to change my GitHub user settings to give me a custom prefix in this interface?